# How do I change the color of dots in pgf?I tried many ways however each of them failed

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw dots of green however the below attempts failed.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
   
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[]

            \foreach \i in {1,...,10}{

            \addplot[green,scatter,mark size=1pt]coordinates{(\i,0)};

            \addplot[fill=green,scatter,mark size=1pt]coordinates{(\i,1)};

            \addplot[color=green,scatter,mark size=1pt]coordinates{(\i,2)};


            }
        
            \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What can I do for next?

Comment: Any reason you use `scatter` and not just `marks only`?

Comment: No reason. As I set config of **[color=green,only marks,mark size=1pt]** from your advice, the thing worked.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `scatter`  and add `only marks`

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
   
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[]

            \foreach \i in {1,...,10}{

            \addplot[color=green,only marks,mark size=1pt]coordinates{(\i,2)};
           
           %\addplot[color=green,scatter,mark size=1pt]coordinates{(\i,2)};

            }
        
            \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```